# Where I can see traffic gathered from facebook pixel code

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

By using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api/, I have installed Facebook pixel with viewcontent function on my website. Now where can I see traffic that I am tracking with pixel code and view content function?

I have seen ads manager and graph API but have not got anywhere where I can track statistics of custom audience gathered from pixel code so suggestions or solutions in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can view pixel activity at `https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/pixel/facebook_pixel/?act=[Account ID]`

You can view custom audience sizes at `https://business.facebook.com/asset-library/audience/[Account ID]/?business_id=[Business ID]`